# Leaving a Command Running on a Remote Server

Tags: shell, ssh

Forgive me if this is something I've just completely missed, however, I have a remote server (a NAS) that I'd like to start a command running on, while I do some work locally. Now, I believe I could probably do this with a command like:

```
ssh foo@bar 'cp -Rl /foo/bar /bar/foo'
```

However, I need a return value in my main script from part of the command, so I need it to return but leave the `cp` command running. For example:

```
foo=$(ssh foo@bar <<- REMOTE_COMMANDS
    cp -Rl /foo/bar /bar/foo &
    echo "foobar"
REMOTE_COMMANDS)
```

However I don't believe this returns until the `cp` command has completed, but if I use `exit` I think the `cp` is interrupted?

Is there another way to leave `cp` running, or will I need to run two `ssh` commands (one for the `cp`, one to get the return value I need?)

Comment: Use `screen`, or `tmux`, you can even reconnect later to the session if you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one the following choices :

- tmux
- nohup
- screen

`tmux` & `screen` are some complete environments that can be *attached* and *detached* for **1 to N** users.

If you need something straightforward, look `nohup` first.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like my NAS doesn't support `tmux` or `screen`, so `nohup` it shall be, thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **screen** command.
Simply create a new screen using : `screen -R screen_name`.
Run your command or code and then exit that screen by pressing **ctrl + a + d**.
If you want to switch back to the screen, enter this command : `screen -r screen_name`.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Rather then `screen -R`, it seems the OP most likely wants to start it in detached mode (`screen -d -m`). Note that with screen over ssh you may need to force tty allocation in the ssh parameters.

Comment: yeah I think that is exactly what the OP wants. :-)